# file structure with google's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, .htaccess, directory, seo, structure

I have a question regarding file structure with google's algorithm.

Would it make a difference to use a physical file structure for your site opposed to using a rewrite rule in a htaccess file? Would google know the difference? 
For instance

```
public_html/
    index.php
    about/index.php
    other/index.php
```

Or using a rewrite rule to change the filename to a directory

```
public_html/
    index.php
    about.php
    other.php
```

I'm not great with htaccess stuff but I think the script would be?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./$1.php
```

Would there be any difference to the behaviour in which google and other search engines finds and displays your urls?

Concidering I'm reading page 8 of **[this](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.co.uk/en/uk/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf)** resource:

Comment: Google only knows URLs. It doesn't matter if your content is completely generated or completely static.

Comment: Ohhh ok cool thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**[This](https://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjo74TeqK7LAhVCP5oKHcKLAMgQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhimmele.googlecode.com%2Fsvn%2Ftrunk%2FSearch%2520Engines%2FGoogle-%2520Data%2520Structures%2520and%2520Algorithms.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFaESOXfAneUaD3L1jiM6WJ_pXg7w&sig2=g70Fa4fjBhYJ_X2Xmn0vHw&bvm=bv.116274245,d.bGs&cad=rja)** is great read for google data structures.

Google just wants to know url and their crawlers will do the rest of job. There are few good reads for this, one is up above. There are difference in behaviour if you are optimizing your site. Best practice is not to use rewrite or redirections.